# TinyMCE configure third row

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, html-editor

In [TinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor](http://www.tinymce.com/), There is a third row which includes icons such as `Insert horizontal ruler, Remove formatting, Subscript, Superscript, etc`. These icons seem to come by default with the editor as there seems to be no way of changing them. .

[TinyMCE... http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/6431/tinymce.png](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/6431/tinymce.png)

I would like to be able to choose which one I want to display, for example, let's say I only want the Subscript and Superscript icons (not the other ones)

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the theme_advanced_buttons option for TinyMCE :)

Here's a link to TinyMCE documentation:

[Button Themes](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_buttons_1_n)

I happen to have an example using TinyMCE's jQuery plugin but you can do it with "stock" tinyMCE as well:

```
$('#bio').tinymce({
    script_url : '/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    theme : 'advanced',
    theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,underline,|,undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist',
    theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
    theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
    theme_advanced_buttons4: '',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'bottom',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'center',
});
```

In this particular case, I'm actually disabling the other toolbars -- but you can put whatever you want.  The buttons it understands are documented here:

[TinyMCE Button Documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls)

Comment: `theme_advanced_buttons3: '',` just remove everything from that row (in that case the third row), me I don't want to just remove the row, I want to be able to select the icons I want to display in that row

Comment: actually, just doing this works `theme_advanced_buttons3 : "my_icons_list"`, thanks for the helpful links